# What's the best way to move everything off of system folder on to s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp, hosting, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Exploring around S3's UI, it seems they only enjoy file uploads from my local box. Is there a way to push the files directly from my production server to an s3 account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've tagged your question *ruby-on-rails* I will suggest the [AWS::S3 gem](http://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/tree/master). I use it myself to copy daily MySQL database dumps from my production server to S3 ([blog entry with the details](http://johntopley.com/2009/09/14/back-up-your-rails-application-to-the-cloud) if you're interested).

Comment: I did a scp login:login [orig path] [dest path] to my local box, and then i'm going to upload it to my s3. I use the AWS::S3 Gem. But more than the sql db, I've been keeping all user photos on my server directly. Ha! It started getting heavy very fast, so now i'm pulling it all off and on to s3.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon doesn't offer a pull service for FTP to S3, and I haven't seen anyone else advertising one either. (It's not a terrible business idea though.)

That having been said, there are a ton of tools to help with this!

A lot of people use something like [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) with their favorite backup utility (ie, cron + rsync).

Lately, I've had great success with [boto](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) and some custom Python scripts. The reason I like this is because it integrates nicely with whatever other services you're running on the box, and gives status updates.

Hope that helps!

Best,

Zach

Comment: Yah I really wish there was a way to go direct to direct. You can't ssh into Amazon S3 can you?

Comment: Indeed you can! I've written a shell script that starts up an EC2 instance, connects via SSH, has the EC2 box download data from an FTP site to it's local disk, and then upload the new data to S3.

Answer (score 0):

I had done massives upload with the s3fox add of firefox.